Do Stoics endure things that illogical and unreasonable people believe to be not worth enduring?
So I was trying to get started into Ryan Holiday's podcast "The Daily Stoic" since he was all over my social media feeds and I have just recently bought Spotify Premium.
In a specific episode entitled How To Make The World A Better Place, he told:

The Stoics have cultivated and inner citadel of strength that allows
them to endure things that the logical people, reasonable men, believe
just aren't worth it. This is how to make the world a better place.

So, for example:
I am a student at this private high school, and even though my education is being paid by government incentives to our private high school, the administration of this private high school still sets some of our rules and conduct in our school.
The administration, trying to cut costs, decides to not fix the air conditioning units in our school. For a reasonable and logical student, they would say "You guys are being paid through government incentives to give us a conducive learning environment for us to be more effective in learning whatever it is expected for us to learn!" I would say that this demand sounds logical - even highly reasonable - to voice out the students concerns. It is the right of the students to demand such conditions, even though that it is not the students themselves who pays miscellaneous fees to the school. The facilities of the school also fails to cater certain needs of the students, such as a decent science laboratory for STEM students, a functional kitchen for Home Economics students, fully functioning computer lab for ICT students.
So, would a Stoic overcome such demand by cultivating inner peace, strength, and patience to endure the struggle of being in a classroom that makes it difficulty for anyone to concentrate given the fact the the design of the room is for it to rely on air conditioned ventilation than open air ventilation?
Another example:
I am working as a teacher in this same private high school, and we have this toxic, micro-managing superior that interferes with every small teachings, decision, and whatever academic freedom that the entire faculty practices that are still within the bounds of the curriculum that the government set for the students. For example, he would ask the teachers not to go outside of their classroom for a quick restroom/comfort room/toilet breaks, or they would not allow the faculty member to dismiss the class even a few seconds early and would insist to fully utilize ever second of the class even though the topic for that meeting has been done. He would give sacred cows such as paper cows (paper works that clearly doesn't have any importance and is only there to waste the faculty's time), meeting cows (unnecessary faculty meetings that is actually beyond the working hours of the faculty and the admin wouldn't pay the faculty members for additional overtime pay, or the meeting will be held during class hours, and instead of delivering your lecture to your class, you would listen to unnecessary banters of this superior), and even speed cows (setting deadlines for paper works and tasks that can be actually set at a later time and wouldn't affect its impact).  This superior would even scream and lash out at faculty members in front of their students, potentially letting the students see that their teachers, who are a symbol of leadership and guidance, be disrespected by their superiors, all for simply dismissing the class early even though the lecture has been delivered, the faculty has to pee or get some stuff in the faculty room, relocating their class to a different room since the air conditioning unit for their assigned room is defective, and so on. This superior would also set school activities that wouldn't enhance student learning and immersion and these activities would very much interfere with the planned lessons of the faculty throughout the entire semester. A reasonable and logical co-faculty would professionally communicate such concerns to this superior, stating "These paper works, meetings, deadlines, rules, conduct, and other things you imposed seems to affect us into performing our duties in our own ways, and we ask you to re-evaluate your stance on these matters." And he would, of course, not listen to it and interpret it as an insult to the "values" of the school.
Would a Stoic disregard the reasonable and logical request of her co-worker faculty to "re-evaluate her stance" towards her imposed rules into the schools and, once again, cultivate inner peace, strength, and patience by finding "meaningful struggle" even though such situations seems illogical, if not unfair?

In sofar as one has no choice in the matter and has to endure the situation, its better, even if you're not a Stoic, to remain calm and "Stoic" about it, if possible, since not doing so may increase the harm to oneself.  At the same time, it would be good to try to change the situation by finding allies, among students and parents, investigate the power structure, see if you can influence the money stream, possibly replace the principal... If the situation is really intolerably bad, get media involved... (I sure would not want to have my kids in a school like that.)

You should have boldfaced "allows them" as well, having a strength does not compel its exercise in every case. Stoics generally distinguish what is "in our control" and out of, and the endurance is primarily aimed at the latter. Real world situations are messy, neither in nor out of our control entirely, so the due degree of endurance is decided on a case by case basis. Holiday suggests that "making the world a better place" may need more of it than "logical reasonable people" would find worthwhile, not that it should be indiscriminate, especially when things are in our control.

thank you mudskipper and Conifold for your answers!

Possibly a better question for The Workplace SE or Academia SE.
